# ¿Como puedo hacer visible mis paginas web con subdominios?

Tags: php, api, nginx, servidor, dominio

Dispongo de un dominio comprado en google con acceso a ilimitados subdominios y me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que mis proyectos web sean accesibles desde internet configurando varios subdominios con el mismo dominio, me explico:

Tengo 2 proyectos web que se comunican entre si, uno es una api y el otro es el cliente que consume la api, entonces me gustaría que mi api fuera accesible desde internet escribiendo "api.midominio.com" y que a mi pagina web se pudiera acceder desde "www.midominio.com" pero no tengo ni idea de como conseguirlo y que tengo que hacer. ¿debería bajarme algun programa? ¿lo configuro desde domains.google.com?

Por si os sirve, el servidor web bajo el que trabajo es NGINX y no dispongo de ip estatica, sería todo con dynamic dns... pero repito, no tengo ni idea.

¿Podrían ayudarme? gracias

Answer (score 0):

### Ingresa al panel que Google te da al contratar sus servicios

Doy por entendido que ya conoces la diferencia entre un servicio de almacenamiento y uno de dominios. En caso de que no, igual te dejo un enlace al final para que te des una mejor idea.

En pocas palabras, Google te da un manual para hacer lo que deseas. Y toda la información que necesitas esta aquí:

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6072198?hl=es

Que mejor que obtener la información del mismo lugar que contrataste sus servicios, así solo aclaro tu duda y evito copiar todo el contenido del manual que alguien en Google ya hizo. Espero te sirva.

**Hosting y dominios:** https://comalis.com/ayuda/diferencia-dominio-hosting

Comment: Obtengo un usuario y una password de google para cada subdominio dinamico que creo, pero repito que no se que tengo que hacer con ese usuario y esa contraseña, supongo que son unas credenciales para meter en algun tipo de programa que resolverá esas credenciales, pero sigo sin saber donde tengo que meterlas